# QSqlQuery placeholder for table

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qt5, c++14

[Here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1702010) is says placeholders do not work for table name. Why?

```
QSqlQuery query(db);
qDebug() << query.prepare("SELECT :parameter FROM :table");
query.bindValue(":parameter", parameter);
query.bindValue(":table", table);
```

How to overcome that issue?

I'm using MySQL-5.6.17.

Comment: Parameters can only appear where a literal (e.g. a quoted string, or a number) would be allowed by syntax. *"How to overcome that issue?"* `query.prepare(QString("SELECT %1 FROM %2").arg(parameter).arg(table));`

Comment: Ok. This works. But I'll appreciate to see a complete answer with examples.

Comment: As you are using ":" in your place holder, you are connecting to Oracle database. And Oracle did not allow place holders for tables. Search for  "Placeholders cannot be used to name other Oracle objects such as tables or columns." in below link. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96584/oci05bnd.htm

Comment: The exact reason i also do not know, but I heard from some search that, the  place holder for table name may alter query.